# Error connecting from Google AppEngine Standard to Google Cloud SQL instance (Using NodeJS)

Tags: mysql, node.js, cloud, google-cloud-sql

I've created a small NodeJS REST API connecting to Google Cloud SQL. using Google AppEngine Flexible environment it works, but when I try to use the Standard environment Google Cloud SQL connection is refused.

I've tried to use the internal IP as well as the socketPath to connect.

I've created a repository to showcase the error: https://github.com/cbullokles/appengine-error

According to documentation, I expect to connect to MySQL in both cases, but it is not working as expected. Is it a non-documented limitation? Or maybe I didn't read correctly AppEngine docs.

Answer (score 1):

The way to [connect to Cloud SQL instances from App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine#connecting_the_standard_environment_to) is using the Unix domain socket for connecting to Cloud SQL instances that provides the App Engine standard environment.

If you use the Node.js `mysql` package configure it this way to run in App Engine:

```
const db = mysql.createConnection ({
    socketPath: '/cloudsql/<PROJECT_NAME>:<REGION_NAME>:<INSTANCE_NAME>',
    user: 'user',
    password: '1234',
    database: 'yourDatabase'
});
```

The `<PROJECT_ID>:<REGION>:<INSTANCE_ID>` is a unique string for each Cloud SQL instance. It is listed under **Instance connection** name on the **Instance details page** for your instance, or under `connectionName` when using the `gcloud sql instances describe <INSTANCE_ID>` command.

Also the App Engine Standard official documentation for Node.js has some [code samples](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-sql) for connecting using the [`knex`](https://knexjs.org/) library.